# Pointer for array to calculate average in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I got a question on pointer in C++ :

> Write a function that computes the average value of an array of floating-point data:
>
> double average(double* a, int size)
>
> In the function, use a pointer variable, not an integer index, to traverse the array elements.

And here is my solution :

```
int main()
{
const int size = 5;
double num_array[] = {2,2,3,4,5}; 
double* a = num_array;
cout << average(a,size);
cout << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

double average(double* a,const int size)
{
double total = 0;
for (int count =0; count< size; count++){
    total = total + *(a + count);
}
return total/size;
}
```

It works fine but I have question on the for loop on pointer in average function. If I replace the statement in for loop with :

```
    total = total + a*;
```

(I thought we supposed to do like this to add up all the number in array but unfortunately it gives me the wrong answer)

So what does the *(a + count) do? If possible, can somebody please simply brief me on how it works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*(a + count)` does *exactly* the same as `a[count]`. The question asks you to use a pointer variable but your answer doesn't do that. It uses an integer index namely `count`.

Comment: instead of `const int size = 5;` let the compiler compute the number with something like `sizeof num_array / sizeof num_array[o]`

Comment: Ya I used this way before but my teacher said it is always better to initialise the size and pass the size along in C++. Thanks

Comment: @Rauryn Maybe with this he only wanted you to pass a size parameter to the function. Because *within* the function, you can't use `sizeof`, since you lost the array information (it's only a pointer, and pointers don't carry size information, they only *point* to the first element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is a pointer to a `double`.

If you write `*a`, this pointer gets *dereferenced* and you get the data where the pointer *points at*, i.e. the `double` value. Note that the asterisk has to be *in front of* the pointer. (It's a "prefix" unary operator.)

`a*` is no valid syntax (it tries to *multiply* `a` with something which still has to follow ...)

`a + count` is pointer arithmetic. It gives you `a` but with `count` numbers of elements offset to the original `a` pointer. So it now points to the `count`-th element in the array.

`*(a + count)` now dereferences exactly this pointer, which gives you the `count`-th element of the array.

`a[count]` is exactly the same; it's just a nicer syntax.

Note: You can also use `a++` in your loop. What it does is it increments the pointer by one position in the array. The next time you dereference `a` using `*a`, it returns the next entry. So your loop can be rewritten like this:

```
double total = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++){
    total = total + *a;    // Access the element a currently points to
    a++;                   // Move the pointer by one position forward
}
```

You can even combine the increment and dereferencing operations into one expression. The postfix-increment syntax `a++` will return the old pointer and increment the pointer by one position. Dereferencing `a++` now means that you dereference the old pointer.

```
double total = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < size; count++){
    total = total + *(a++);
}
```

The second note I want to give you is that you don't need your integer variable here to count the element. Since your pointer now already carries the information, your counter is now only used to stop the loop. This can also be done by comparing the pointer with some "end pointer", which we keep in a variable:

```
double total = 0;
double *end = a + size; // Store the end of the array
while(a < end) {
    total = total + *(a++);
}
```

As you can see, I converted the `for` loop into a `while` loop since I no longer need to initialize or increment something (remember: going to the next entry of the array is done in the body!).

I hope this illustrates pointer arithmetic a little bit. You can "calculate" with pointers similarly as with indexing variables (your `count` variable). You can even subtract them to calculate offsets between pointers, for example.

Comment: So can I explain in this way : when there is a loop to loop thru array item, the pointer which point to the array item need to be increase also? You can't just increase the loop without increasing the pointer else your pointer will always be pointed to first element?

Comment: Either you keep your pointer as it is and use something like `a[offset]`. `offset` is then an integer variable, like your `count`. **OR** you modify a pointer while going through the array. Keep in mind that the pointer is still *modified* when you're done with the loop. So this should only be done in a separate function like your `average` function. Or copy the pointer before starting with the loop, like `double *current = a`, then only use `current` in the loop. This is even nicer, since you don't touch the *original* array pointer `a`.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks a lot. I need to work harder on pointer tho.

Comment: By the way how could I fix the program if there is 0 in the array because if I insert 0 to array, I can't even run the program, it just prompt an error message although I wrote a if else statement

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean... In the code in your question you don't read from the console or line; the array content is within your code. Can you show me the code you are talking about? You can use pastebin/ideone or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is the dereferencing operator, operating on the address a increased by count.

Read [Pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Comment: Thank you. I've got the answer from post above.